# Inplace redirect in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, url-parameters, html5-history

I'm writing a Chrome extension to seamlessly inject URL params on a certain domain.

For instance, when you're visiting `search.com/?q=query`, it should redirect you to `search.com/q=query&new_param=1`.

The following background script works fine:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  var url = changeInfo.url;
  if (
    url &&
    url.startsWith("https://search.com/?") &&
    !url.includes('&new_param=')
  ) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: newUrl});
  }
});
```

But this redirect creates 2 entries in navigation history: with and without the new parameter.

It is bad because going back in history - to the page without the parameter - triggers the redirect again. And you're stuck unless you manually jump 2 pages in history back.

How can I keep the `Back` button UX the same as without the extension?

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest API, see the [official demos](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest) and google up more examples if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's much better now, the only part when it does work is when I manually click some link on the page. I need to either refresh the page or put it to the address bar manually - then it injects the param. Is it normal?

Comment: It looks like `onBeforeRedirect` can't be used for the purpose of injecting parameters, and onBeforeRequest only reacts to newly opened URLs - either reloaded or manually typed. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The correct event is onBeforeRequest and there are no such limits as you've described or I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: For me, `onBeforeRequest` doesn't capture the simplest redirect - clicking a link on the page. Say, there's a link pointing to `https://search.com`. When I click on it, `https://search.com` gets opened. When I reload the page, it changes to `https://search.com/?new_param=1`. The script is at https://pastebin.com/Xtzt6min

Comment: I tried to debug it using alerts too. When I clicked the link, it showed a bunch of XHR requests and redirected me to the new page. The redirect URL wasn't among those XHRs...

Comment: In your script `"*://mysite.com/"` matches only the main page URL. Add a `*` at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199196/discussion-between-gukoff-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

Javascript also has window.history.replaceState, but I'm not sure if that works within the chrome extension sandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. `history` points not to the history of a tab, but to the history of generic `_generated_background_page`, where extension scripts are running. Is there a way to access the history of a certain tab?

Comment: If that doesn't work, its ugly, but the only other possibility I know of would be to use the normal window.history functionality with something like 'chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    var jsCode = "alert('history code')'";
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: jsCode}, function(response) {
        ...
    });
});'